# css and js repeat download problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, download

Hi:
IN my application,I have to use the IFrame.

For example,the Default.aspx:

```
.....
<body>
  <iframe src="01.aspx" .../>
  <iframe src="02.aspx" .../>
  <iframe src="03.aspx" .../>
  .........
</body>
```

The o1/02/03.aspx use some same css and js,for example:

01.aspx's head:

```
<script src="main.js" ... />
```

In 02.aspx'head:

```
<script src="main.js" ... />
```

When I run the Default.aspx,I found the main.js is downloaded three times according the firebug,I wonder why?

**UPDATE:**

Default.aspx:

```
<html>
    <head><title>default page</title></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="common/01.aspx" scroll="auto" />
        <iframe src="common/02.aspx" scroll="auto" />
        <iframe src="common/03.aspx" scroll="auto" />
    </body>
</html>
```

01.aspx:

```
<html>
    <head><title></title>
        <script type="javascript" src="js/main.js"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="01">
        ......
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

02.aspx:

```
<html>
    <head><title></title>
        <script type="javascript" src="js/main.js"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="02">
        ......
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
table{
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid blue;
}
....
```

Comment: Can you also add the source code for main.js?

Comment: Hi,I update the css file which is also shared by all the iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple - each `iframe` must *individually* load `main.js` (and the other assets).

Firebug is showing all the HTTP requests from inside all the `iframe`s.

Comment: so,if I have no choice but use the iframe,then there is no way to improve the speed of the downoading time?

Comment: You can make a global js file and include it in default.aspx.

Comment: I have tried include the main.js in the head of the Default.aspx,but it seems that it does not work in the iframe.

Comment: This because in your main.js you must refer to the iframes. If you can, post the source code (Or a snippet) in this question.

Comment: @dmarucco:thanks for your attention,I have updated my post.:)

Answer (score 1):

iframes are separate pages, it is like you have 1 page, clik in a link and go to a 2 page and click in a link and go in to a 3 page, if page1, page2 and page 3 use main.js it is loaded 3 times.

if dont want 3 times load dont use iframes